# Flutter Provider with Laravel Login redirecting with code 302 while trying to register with same email id

Tags: laravel, flutter

I am trying to register user and while it works fine, but when user try to create account again with same email id, it is redirecting to Homepage with status 302. This seems to be working fine while I am sending POST request with same mail id, but when i do it from Flutter App, it redirects to Homepage with 302 error.

```
  public function register(Request $request)
   {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required|max:55',
            'email'=>'email|required|unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|confirmed',
            'mobile' => 'required|max:12', 
        ]);

        $validatedData['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);

        $user = User::create($validatedData);

        $accessToken = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;

        return response(['result' => true, 'user'=> $user, 'access_token'=> $accessToken]);
       
   }
```

App Sign Up Provider

```
 Future signUp(String name, String email, String mobile, String password,
      String passwordconfirmation) async {
    final url = 'https://androidapp.factory2homes.com/api/register';
    final response = await http.post(url, body: {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'mobile': mobile,
      'password': password,
      'password confirmation': passwordconfirmation,
    });
    print(json.decode(response.body));
    var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(response.body);
    print(json.decode(response.body));
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: you are using unique rule, so the validation fails and you are redirected.

Comment: Can you suggest code for this to work

Comment: so if the email can be used multiple times, how do you identify users??

Comment: Email is identifier and if email  already exist, i just want to throw error that email exits and then i can show it as error in app

Comment: I am not sure on reason but when i am sending post request from postman app with existing email id,, i do get error in Json format, but when i send it via mobile app, it redirects

Comment: i think you are missing  `accept:application/json` in your mobile app request header.

Comment: Correct, I updated `accept:application/json` in different api. missed to update in signup api.

Comment: i am adding an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when laravel validation fails in an api request it generally redirects to a url and that's why the 302 status code comes. if you want a json response for validation error you have to send the following line in your api request header.

```
accept:application/json
```

laravel will return json when it finds this in the request header.